# How to set default attribute value to today's date - MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I am building a database application with C# in Visual Studio 2013. The application is meant to email a customer 90 days after the date of their visit so, when they come in, their info is taken and today's date is stored with their other information.

I have a table called `Customer` ready to store customer information but instead of having the user type the date for each customer and risk them screwing up the format, I would like the default value for the column named `DateOfVisit` to be today's date.

[image: here's what my Customer table looks like]

I am looking for what to type into the default column. Something along the lines of `getDate()` that will give me today's date in a format that I can easily check against another future date and see if 90 days have past or not.

EXTRA: From the picture, you may notice I have the `emailFlag`'s data type set to bit because I thought that would be the closest thing to a boolean. The purpose of `emailFlag` is that before a customer is sent an email, that flag will be checked and if it's false the email will go through and the flag will be set to true, so as to avoid spamming the customer emails in case the program messes up. Is this a good idea? Do you have any suggestions as to how I could do it better?

tl;dr
I need a method that will give me today's date to store in a database and that I can compare with other dates.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.Customer ADD CONSTRAINT df DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR DateOfVisit`

Comment: So you have already registered the customer for the first time, then when he visits again the site you need to UPDATE its record with the current date right?

Comment: **Please copy and paste the code from the image to question, as images aren't search-engine friendly and might go stale after some time**.

Comment: @Everyone Thanks for the responses. It seems I can just throw "getDate()" into that default box.

Comment: @Steve Yes, it will perform that function eventually, but before that, 90 days after the DateOfVisit, the program will email that customer telling them it's time to come back for maintenance. So in what format does getDate() return the date so that compare it to another date and see if 90 days have past?

Comment: @Seb, you're right. I'm sorry about that. It's my first post and it made it seem like it would just post a link to the image. It even had me type in link text :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In case you already have the table created

```
Alter Table dbo.customer Drop Column DateOfVisit;
```

Lets alter the table and add a field with the deafult value date

```
Alter Table dbo.customer ADD DateOfVisit DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE());
```